# Handle DB Fail-over on postgres

Tags: java, database, postgresql, failover

Can anyone help with the following?

- Is there any solution to feature similar to Oracle TAF (Transparent application Fail-over) in Postgres database
- Else how database fail-overs handled on industry level in Java code? Is there any solution other than retry the query with a timer?

Comment: No there is nothing similar to TAF in Postgres

Comment: So DO you know what are the stranded methods to handle persist data in a java program with PG HA setup.

Answer (score 1):

TAF is partly a lie - [data modifying statements won't fail over](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jjdbc/transparent-application-failover.html#GUID-95B3215D-A988-4619-94BD-0C6F56B8F43C). And no, there is no such thing in PostgreSQL.

I don't see the need for a timer. What you do to make your application resilient to failovers is to examine the SQLSTATE of the error you got, and if it indicates connection loss, you repeat the transaction. Keep a count so that you don't end up looping endlessly if the error is persistent.

Comment: [Quote from the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jjdbc/transparent-application-failover.html#GUID-95B3215D-A988-4619-94BD-0C6F56B8F43C) "*Transparent Application Failover (TAF) is a feature of the Java Database Connectivity (JDBC) Oracle Call Interface (OCI) driver. It enables the application to automatically reconnect to a database, if the database instance to which the connection is made fails. In this case, the active transactions roll back*"